# Is there a way to check if Android device screen is Locked/Unlocked using C?

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel

I need to know how to get screen status (Locked/Unlocked) or accessing keyguard status using C. I already checked for **ISRs** on **/proc/interrupts** for changes while unlocking the screen, here I watched for changes on interrupts with `watch -n0.2 "cat /proc/interrupts"` but I didn't find anything related to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by watching **/proc/boot_stat** monitoring *finishUserUnlockedCompletedstatus*.

```
watch -n1 "cat /proc/boot_stat | grep 'finishUserUnlockedCompleted'"
```